# Display Hyperlink in C# Datagrid

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access

I have an MS Access database which I am accessing via a C# tool. The code below just populates a DataGridView with the contents of the MS database. The only problem I have is that one column in the database contains hyperlinks to PDF documents saved in a different location. In the database itself the hyperlinks work without any problem, however when populating the DataGridView with the hyperlinks, the "/" gets replaced with a "%" and the link does not work anymore. Does anybody know how I can get the hyperlinks working in the DataGridView?

```
        string Name = Name.Text;

        //Load Data
        string connStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=P:User\Database.mdb";
        string query = "SELECT Doc_Type,Date,Link FROM Contracts WHERE Name = '" + Name +"'";
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
        {
            using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn))
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds);
                LegalGrid.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            }
        }
```

Comment: Post sample hyperlinks before and after reading.

Comment: You sure they're not being changed to `%2F`, which is a slash?